# Kaggle JSON file is in the correct folder but I am still getting the "could not find kaggle.json" error

Tags: kaggle

Please see images below!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWuf8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMqwj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmOWT.png)

My Kaggle JSON file is in my .kaggle file. However, I am still getting this "OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method." error.

I followed all the instructions, but not sure what I am doing wrong.